# attribute references not allowed in lexer actions

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, lexer

I found a simple grammar to start learning ANTLR. I put it in the myGrammar.g file. here is the grammar:

```
grammar myGrammar;
/* This will be the entry point of our parser. */
eval
    :    additionExp
    ;

/* Addition and subtraction have the lowest precedence. */
additionExp
    :    multiplyExp 
         ( '+' multiplyExp 
         | '-' multiplyExp
         )* 
    ;

/* Multiplication and division have a higher precedence. */
multiplyExp
    :    atomExp
         ( '*' atomExp 
         | '/' atomExp
         )* 
    ;
atomExp
    :    Number
    |    '(' additionExp ')'
    ;

/* A number: can be an integer value, or a decimal value */
Number
    :    ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
    ;

/* We're going to ignore all white space characters */
WS  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

when I use this command :

> java -jar /usr/local/...(antlr path)  /home/ali/Destop/...(myGrammar.g path)

I have this error:

> myGrammar.g:39:36: attribute references not allowed in lexer actions: $channel

what is the problem and what should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it looks like you are using antlr4, so please replace `{$channel=HIDDEN;}` with `-> channel(HIDDEN)`.

example:

```
/* We're going to ignore all white space characters */
WS  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I also replace

> WS:   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};

with this:

> WS        :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') -> skip;

and it worked.